# Java how to force classpath in compile to be the same as in test

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have a maven project. When I run it under Netbeans 11 (the command displayed by Netbeans is :  `mvn "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath myPackage.MyMain" -DOMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1 -DskipTests=true org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java`) and print the classpath with `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path").replace(":","\n"));` it only shows a single jar

> /path/to/netbeans/java/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar

So I can't check which libraries are actually included.

On the contrary when I run a test it show all jars that are included :

```
...
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/github/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core/1.4.0/jai-imageio-core-1.4.0.jar
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/github/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-jpeg2000/1.4.0/jai-imageio-jpeg2000-1.4.0.jar
/home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/pdfbox/jbig2-imageio/3.0.2/jbig2-imageio-3.0.2.jar
/home/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/tika/tika-parsers/1.21/tika-parsers-1.21.jar
...
```

How can I have the same behavior at compile time as the one I have at test time and show the actual included jars ?

The pom.xml reads :

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>  
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>  
            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>${tikaVersion}</version>         
        </dependency>
```

The building part of pom reads like :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>
                        ${mainClass}
                    </mainClass>                                    
                </manifest>

                <manifestEntries>
                    <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                    <Implementation-Title>${project.artifactId}</Implementation-Title>
                </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And the execution part reads like :

```xml
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
            <argLine>-Xmx1024M</argLine>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${javaVersion}</source>
            <target>${javaVersion}</target>                    
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You need to show your pom.xml. The dependencies included on the classpath depend on the scopes of each dependency.

Comment: I included the pom.xml @tgdavies. But doesn't <scope>test</test> also includes all <scope>compile</scope> ? So if it is in test then it must also be in compile, mustn't it ?

Comment: You're supplying `exec.args`, so the classpath will be whatever gets substituted for `%classpath`. This is a Netbeans issue, not a maven issue.

Comment: What happens if you just run `mvn "-Dexec.args=myPackage.MyMain" -DskipTests=true org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java`

Comment: It outputs the same : `/pathTo/netbeans/java/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar`

Comment: You're sure that your pom doesn't have any configuration for the exec plugin?

Comment: I never run my java programs this way. For example, for the pdfbox app, I use `java -cp "pdfbox-app-2.0.25;./lib/*" org.apache.pdfbox.tools.PDFBox param...param` and the lib subdirectory has the needed jar files. Note that if you're not on windows, you may have to use ":" instead of ";" for the classpath.

Comment: @tgdavies there is configuration for the exec plugin (see my edit) but I think the dependencies management it handled by [`plexus-classworlds`](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-classworlds/) which seems to do dynamic loading under the hood.

Comment: You can try explicitly setting which scope is use for the classpath: https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#classpathScope

Comment: Thank you @tgdavies I tried both compile and test scopes but nothing changed.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I tried your suggestion but it did not lead to the expected results (JPEG2000 still missing). I also tried to copy the jars  (https://pastebin.com/4maHgz4E as you wrote) in the root folder because root folder is automatically in the classpath but it did not work as expected either. Finally with the built jar with dependency, I tried to put the only the missing jars (JAI, JPEG2000, JBIG) under `./lib/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib` because I knew that this path was on the path, and it worked. Still I don't know why it did not worked in ./lib or in . (root).